# After 3 files transferred through SFTP (FileZilla), the queue halts. What could be causing it?

Tags: wireless-networking, sftp, filezilla, fedora-12, buffalo-router

And when it's happening, all I need to do is restart the queue. What could be causing it?

I'm running on 64-bit Fedora 12, using a [Buffalo WHR-G125](http://www.buffalotech.com/products/wireless/wireless-g-125-high-speed/wireless-g-high-speed-router) Wireless Router.

Comment: I experience buggy performance sometimes using FileZilla in Windows.  You may want to try uninstalling/reinstalling and/or updating to the newest version.  What kind of file is the 4th file?  Is it large?

Comment: All files are 32MB. I'm using the latest FileZilla.

Comment: Have you reported this bug to this site yet?  http://trac.filezilla-project.org/wiki/TicketSubmissionGuide

Comment: Filed it just now: http://trac.filezilla-project.org/ticket/5322. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your host might have the max number of connections maxed out. I had this problem once while uploading some files to hostgator. I was troubled because I was up and running on day then next day queue kept stopping. Some guy was uploading a ton of stuff and using up all the connections so i had to adjust my number of connections to one to squeak in there to get my stuff done.
[Here is how to do this.](http://forums.site5.com/showthread.php?t=27500)